# Is Angular2 Injectables and creating instance or same?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I am new to es6, typescript and Angular2 stuff, I have tried directive example. It looks like following..

```
  import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myHighlight]' })

export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
       renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', 'green');
    }
}
```

and i have tried following variants, but didn't work as i expected..

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myHighlight]' })

export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor() {

    console.log(new ElementRef())
       //renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', 'green');
    }
}
```

also tried this..

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myHighlight]' })

export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(ElementRef, Renderer) {

    console.log(new ElementRef())
       //renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', 'green');
    }
}
```

I didn't get the difference between **el: ElementRef** syntax and normal object instance creation with **new ElementrRef** .. Please Explain The Difference And Logic Behind Them and **el: ElementRef** relation and equivalent in normal or es6 js.. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you included your template file in your app.component.ts or did you forget to import it to your app.module declarations?

Comment: Friend , I have included.. and that is not problem here..  The first code sample is working but why the second and third is not working in the same way.. what is the difference in between that code samples.. In first code sample what exactly (el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) this line doing.. ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the basic building stone of angular 2 Dependency Injection (DI) mechanism. In short: if you need in your component reference to some service etc., you can must ask Angular via `constructor`. With line `constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer)` you are basically asking the framework: "When you will construct the highlight directive for me, give me these two objects, `ElementRef` and `Renderer`. Without them, I as a highlight directive cannot live."

And how are these two objects obtained? Through DI framework during lifecycle of directive. I strongly suggest to read this awesome article for better understanding (it is a *must*): http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html

In second and third examples (where your `constructor` is empty so nothing is *injected* to your directive on creation), you cannot simply create `ElementRef` through **new()**, because it requires more dependencies, for example `nativeElement`, as stated here: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html
But you are not providing these and simply cannot.